# Center Android WindowBackground with Activity ImageView

Tags: android, splash-screen

## Context

**Step1:** Currently I have one activity which uses `android:windowBackground` to set the initial background while we wait for the activity to load. This loads a bitmap which should be center aligned.

**Step2:** Once the activity is loaded it does a simple `setContentView` to set the background for the activity which will now replace the `android:windowBackground` from **step1**. This loads an `imageView` which should be center aligned.

The problem is they are not both aligned center, there is some kind of offset on one or the other misaligning them. Maby the statusbar pushing down the one? I am not sure. Any ideas why they are not aligned the same?

I would like to have them both center aligned. I have tried using `fitSystemWindows="true"` with no luck.

When I add `android:layout_marginTop="12dp"` to the activity (`activity_start_onboarding.xml`) layouts `imageView`  both align fine but it does not align for all densities, other densities are misaligned.

Maby there is a way to dynamically calculate this offset to align then for all densities?

---

## Compare Images

**Left (Grey) - Step1 (windowBackground):**
**Right (Blue) - Step2 (activity layout):**
[image]

---

## The Code

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<activity android:name=".view.onboarding.ActivityStartOnboarding"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/ColdstartSplashTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**styles.xml**

```xml
<style name="ColdstartSplashTheme" parent="SuperbalistTheme.Dark">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

**@drawable/splash_background**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/grey_mid_dark" />

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delivery_free_raster" />
</item>
```

**ActivityStartOnboarding.java**

```java
public class ActivityStartOnboarding extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_onboarding);
  }
}
```

**activity_start_onboarding.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue_light_darker"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_background" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Why do you use `splash_background` in `activity_start_onboarding.xml` but `ic_delivery_free_raster` in `splash_background` ?

Comment: Hi, just for illustration purposes. So that the theme/style uses the same layout as the activity. `@drawable/splash_background`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

That is your problem. Your FrameLayout start to inflate under statusbar, which height ~25dp, therefore AppCompatImageView a bit higher.

First solution:
Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `activity_start_onboarding.xml` FrameLayout.

Second solution:
Add `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>` to your `ColdstartSplashTheme`. The background starts drawing under status bar and bitmap will be higher.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply! 

1. Removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` does in fact make it draw slightly lower. Bringing them closer

2. `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>` does in fact bring it up higher and both are now aligned perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer an apologies for not getting back sooner :O

Answer (score 4):

For me the accepted solution didn' work. But I found [this](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/241#issuecomment-458985596) and it worked like a charm.
Its also a more flexible solution because it doesn't depend on API 21

Answer (score 3):

Use background instead of windowBackground

```
<style name="ColdstartSplashTheme" parent="SuperbalistTheme.Dark">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the input! When I use `android:background` instead of `android:windowBackground` the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_onboarding);` has no effect so I never see the second screen (Step2/blue screen). Any ideas?

Comment: @Francois Hi! I answered yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998465/8971623). Did you try my solutions?
It should work

Comment: Hi I will have a look at it tomorrow :) tx!

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions above solved this problem for me. I have a single activity app and after a while, of researching a solution I got solved by adding the code below to my splash screen fragment **onViewCreated**:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(requireActivity().window, false)
```

This code says to android that we will handle the window insets ourselves. So it doesn't adapt the layout with the status bar and the bottom navigation bar.

I also added:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(requireActivity().window, true)
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Just to keep the behavior that I currently had on the rest of the app.

A great resource that helped me with the solution was: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acC7SR1EXsI

**note: This solution works with gesture and button navigation.**

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me, for whatever reason. So, I wrote a quick class similar to ImageView, except that **it centers the drawable that it's given relative to the whole window** rather than within its own view bounds.

Essentially `windowBackground` in your theme uses the bounds of the **window**. Your `ImageView`, even when it fills its parent, is still restricted by the bounds of your **activity**, which is a different shape (e.g. doesn't include system bar). So centering a drawable in your **window** (what `windowBackground` does) gives different results to centering a drawable in your **view** (what an `ImageView` does). The `View` class I wrote centers the drawable in the **window**, so it does the same thing as your theme.

Here's the class:

```
package your.package.name

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Point
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import your.package.name.R

/**
 * Simply draws the given drawable in the center of the current window with no scaling. This is not
 * very sophisticated, so cannot handle a lot of the features that a regular [ImageView] can. If
 * these features are required, you might want to try subclassing [ImageView].
 */
class WindowCenteredImageView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View(context, attrs) {

    // Obtain drawable from attributes.
    private val d: Drawable?
    init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.WindowCenteredImageView,
            0, 0
        ).apply {
            try {
                d = getDrawable(R.styleable.WindowCenteredImageView_src)
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        if (d != null) {
            // We have a drawable, so try to draw it!
            if (d.intrinsicWidth >= 0 && d.intrinsicHeight >= 0) {
                // Our drawable doesn't fill the screen, so we should calculate its bounds. This is
                // where we take into account the current view's offset within the window...
                val viewTopLeftRelativeToWindow = onDrawCachedObjects.point1.apply {
                    val array = onDrawCachedObjects.array.apply { getLocationInWindow(this) }
                    set(array[0], array[1])
                }

                // And the window's dimensions...
                // (Casting here can't fail as views are always given activity context.)
                val window = (context as Activity).window.decorView
                val windowHeight = window.height
                val windowWidth = window.width

                // Do the calculations.
                // First, find out where we want the image to go in the window
                val imageTopLeftRelativeToWindow = onDrawCachedObjects.point2.apply {
                    set(
                        (windowWidth / 2) - (d.intrinsicWidth / 2),
                        (windowHeight / 2) - (d.intrinsicHeight / 2)
                    )
                }

                // Now we can calculate where the image should go in the view
                val imageTopLeftRelativeToView = onDrawCachedObjects.point3.apply {
                    set(
                        imageTopLeftRelativeToWindow.x - viewTopLeftRelativeToWindow.x,
                        imageTopLeftRelativeToWindow.y - viewTopLeftRelativeToWindow.y
                    )
                }

                // We have all the information needed to set the image bounds
                d.setBounds(
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.x,
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.y,
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.x + d.intrinsicWidth,
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.y + d.intrinsicHeight
                )
            }

            // Draw the drawable onto the canvas
            d.draw(canvas)
        }
    }

    /** Optimization: Objects to use in [onDraw] to avoid instantiations */
    private val onDrawCachedObjects = object {
        val array = IntArray(2)
        val point1 = Point()
        val point2 = Point()
        val point3 = Point()
    }
}
```

and here's how to use it:

- First you need to put this in your res/values/attrs.xml:

```
    <declare-styleable name="WindowCenteredImageView">
        <!-- Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView. -->
        <attr name="src" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

- Now replace your ImageView with this (it needs to be larger than the drawable that it's going to draw, as wrap content probably doesn't work properly: I just made this view the entire size of the activity using `match_parent` - outside the drawable you give it, it will be transparent):

```
<your.package.name.WindowCenteredImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:src="@drawable/ic_delivery_free_raster"/>
```